# Magento Order Grid filters

Tags: filter, order-grid, sku

I added some columns to my Order grid (Product SKU, name and quantity and shipping method) but since that some filters in my grid doesn't work like Purchased and Total Qty (It redirects to Dashboard).

Sometimes it shows me the error message : Error log record number: 756025165

Is there a solution for that ?

Thank you for advance

Comment: Look in folder var/report, in there will be a file called 756025165 (the error report number)

Comment: Please post the error from the report folder here.

Answer (score 2):

You firstly should change `errors/local.xml.sample` to `errors/local.xml`. It will help you show the error. After that update us what you see.

Answer (score 1):

you should write custom filter for your newly added columns
for example:

```
   $this->addColumn('customer_firstname', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('First Name'),
        'index'=>'customer_firstname',
        'type'  => 'text',
      'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_fnameFilter')
    ));
```

and then create a function fnamefilter and filter it.